Multi Thread with Struct Included String
I couldn't figure out why the string corrupted after thread ended using pthread_join().
Here are C code (not C++) and background:

I am debugging a large program for the segment fault in multi threading. To find the cause, I wrote snippet mostly from the code at "Create a thread from IBM" with similar "struct", which has a string, char*, member. When the thread ended, the string is corrupted.

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // strcpy


typedef struct data {
  char *ret;
  int i;
} data;


void *thread(data* data_shared) {

  printf("thread() entered with argument '%s' and %d \n",
    data_shared->ret, data_shared->i);

  strcpy(data_shared->ret, "This is a test");
  data_shared->i += 1;

  pthread_exit(data_shared);
}


// ----- ----- ----- -----
main() {
  pthread_t thid;
  data* data_shared;

  data_shared = malloc(sizeof(data));
  data_shared->i = 1;
  data_shared->ret = malloc(sizeof(char)); // like pointer of pointer
  strcpy(data_shared->ret, "thread 1");

  if (pthread_create(&thid, NULL, thread, data_shared) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (pthread_join(thid, data_shared) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_join() error");
    exit(3);
  }

  printf("thread exited with '%s' and %d \n",
    data_shared->ret, data_shared->i);

  // free(data_shared->ret);
  free(data_shared);
}

The output is:
thread() entered with argument 'thread 1' and 1
thread exited with '▒ধ`' and 2

  I expect 'this is test' not '▒ধ`'.
Where in the code I have to fix?

data_shared->ret = malloc(sizeof(char)); : Not big enough. Only enough space for a null terminator. strcpy(data_shared->ret, "thread 1"); Bug. Buffer overrun. Memory corruption possible. Haven't even gotten to running a thread yet. Before you get into threading, you need to work on how c-style strings work. You need to provide enough memory to contain the string plus a null terminator.

strcpy(data_shared->ret, "This is a test"); Another buffer overrun. Same problem, not threading related. Make it data_shared->ret = malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_STRING_LENGTH_THAT_WILL_BE_NEEDED + 1 );

I believe that pthread_join(thid, data_shared) should be pthread_join( thid, &data_shared ) instead.

@AviBerger Thanks, I will follow the correct memory allocation. For the malloc at the sub function,  if we allocate memory again in the sub function, wouldn't it change physical memory address? Isn't also against the intension of multi threading (repeated usage of the same memory for variable)? Regarding "pthread_join" input parameter, the "data_shared" is a pointer, so I don't think the operator, "&", needed.

Try data_shared->ret = malloc(strlen("This is a test") + 1);.  Allocate memory for the longer string, plus one for the null terminator.

You could also do sizeof("This is a test").  It includes the + 1 and is resolved at compile time.

When we allocate memory again in the sub function, wouldn't it change physical memory address? Isn't against intension of multi threading (repeated usage of the same memory for variable)?

Is there other changes? The memory still be corrupted.

sizeof(char) is 1 (by definition), so the following allocates a buffer of one char:
data_shared->ret = malloc(sizeof(char));

Then you copy 8 chars into it.
strcpy(data_shared->ret, "thread 1");

Then 15.
strcpy(data_shared->ret, "This is a test");

Fixed:
void *thread( void* arg ) {
  data *data_shared = arg;
  printf( "thread() entered with argument '%s' and %d \n",
    data_shared->ret, data_shared->i );

  free( data_shared->ret );

  data_shared->ret = strdup( "This is a test" );
  data_shared->i += 1;

  pthread_exit( data_shared );  // Or: `return data_shared;`
}

int main() {
  data* data_shared = malloc( sizeof( data ) );
  data_shared->i = 1;
  data_shared->ret = strdup( "thread 1" );

  pthread_t thid;
  if ( ( errno = pthread_create( &thid, NULL, thread, data_shared ) ) != 0 ) {
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit( 1 );
  }

  if ( ( errno = pthread_join( thid, data_shared ) ) != 0 ) {
    perror( "pthread_join() error" );
    exit( 3 );
  }

  printf( "thread exited with '%s' and %d \n",
    data_shared->ret, data_shared->i );

  free( data_shared->ret );
  free( data_shared );
}

strdup allocates a buffer of the correct size, then copies the provided string into it.
Other errors fixed:

The signature of the thread callback was wrong, and the behaviour of the function was undefined as a result. A data * can be converted to a void * and back, but that doesn't mean a void * is compatible with a data * or even the same size. You need a (implicit or explicit) cast to convert it.
Your error handling was relying on errno being set, but pthread_* doesn't set errno.
Memory leak. You never freed the string buffer. (The code was there, but commented out.)


Thanks for going extra steps. I have two questions in "other error" section. For " cast to convert it.", isn't this for C++ (my snippetis in C)? Regarding "memory leak", somehow in my computer, if I keep the both free lines, I got error of NULL Pointer at the second free line. I wonder how you avoid that in your computer.

No, everything I said pertains to C.  data *data_shared = arg; implicitly casts arg from a void * to a data *, just as if data *data_shared = (data *)arg; had been used

I also see your free( data_shared->ret ) code line. As I asked to others, if you remove the memory and allocate again in other thread/sub function, isn't this against multi threading objective (reducing the usage of memory)? Is there a way to replace data in the string memory block like the "i" variable?

Re "I got error of NULL Pointer at the second free line.", Unless strdup failed (due to being out of memory, which is obviously not the case), there's no way data_shared->ret is NULL.

Re "isn't this against multi threading objective (reducing the usage of memory)" The goal of multi-threading is execute to code in parallel, not reducing memory usage. And this doesn't increase memory usage.

Re "Is there a way to replace data in the string memory block like the "i" variable?", If you know how much memory the thread will need in advance, you could allocate enough memory for the larger of the request and the response.

Thanks for explanations. Regarding "NULL" error, sorry for confusion, the second "free" line is free( data_shared ).  So you don't get an error in that line if you use strdup. For multi threading objective and memory usage, would you share why do you have to release the memory at the thread? because the memory size isn't enough for new string?

Same answer. Unless the original malloc returned NULL, there's no way data_shared is NULL when the code reaches free( data_shared ).

Re "why do you have to release the memory at the thread?", Why would you want to wait and keep memory you don't need? (It would also requires copying the pointer somewhere because the next line overwrites the only pointer you have to that memory block.)

Re "because the memory size isn't enough for new string?", Because the buffer might not be large enough. I already said you could start with a large-enough buffer if you knew the size in advance to avoid this. You could also use strlen+realloc+strcpy instead of free+strdup.

Is there any other change needed? I still have corrupted memory, and "free(): double free detected in tcache 2" error...

With suggestion about the memory size by user TNM and type casting by user ikegami along with an example from Educative.io, I found a solution by myself...
Three changed made to perform expected (type casting on receiving side was a hard one to figure out - pthread_join):
  data_shared->ret = malloc(sizeof(char)); -> 
  data_shared->ret = malloc(len_ret * sizeof(char)); 
  void* thread(data* data_shared) -> 
  void *thread(void* arg) 
  if (pthread_join(thid, data_shared) != 0) -> 
  if (pthread_join(thid, (void**)&data_ptr) != 0) 
I also realized that I used the same pointer, "data_shared", when I received the return from the thread using "pthread_join" function.
Here is updated code:
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // strcpy


typedef struct data {
  char *ret;
  int len_ret;
  int i;
} data;


  // pthread_create required  void * (*)(data *)
  //   definition: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html
void *thread(void* arg) {

  data* data_shared = arg;
  printf("thread() entered with argument '%s' and %d \n",
    data_shared->ret, data_shared->i);

  strcpy(data_shared->ret, "This is a test");
  data_shared->i += 1;
  
  pthread_exit((void*)data_shared);
}


// ----- ----- ----- -----
main() {
  int str_len_max = 50;
  pthread_t thid;
  data* data_shared;
  data* data_ptr;

  data_shared = malloc(sizeof(data));
  data_shared->i = 1;
  // One more space is for null terminator
  data_shared->ret = malloc(
    (str_len_max + 1) * sizeof(char)); // like pointer of pointer
  data_shared->len_ret = str_len_max;
  strcpy(data_shared->ret, "thread 1");
  
  // pthread_create required  void * (*)(data *)
  //   defintion: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html
  if ((errno = pthread_create(&thid, NULL, thread, data_shared)) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ((errno = pthread_join(thid, (void**)&data_ptr)) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_join() error");
    exit(3);
  }

  printf("thread exited with '%s' and %d \n",
    data_ptr->ret, data_ptr->i);

  free(data_shared->ret);
  free(data_shared);
}



Your error handling is still wrong. perror uses errno, but pthread_* don't set errno.

You have an off by one error. If the max string length is 50, you need to allocate 50+1 bytes.
